# Como funciona o Date Picker e o Time Picker no android Studio?

Tags: android, app

Estou desenvolvendo um app de marcação de consulta e me parece que estes dois métodos são muito bons. No entanto, gostaria de saber se ao implementar os dois métodos no android studio, o admin poderá ver a data e a hora que o usuário marcou.

Answer (score 1):

O Android fornece alguns controles para escolher hora ou até mesmo uma data específica como caixas de diálogo prontas para usar. Cada selecionador fornece controles para selecionar cada parte do tempo (**hora, minuto, AM / PM**) ou data (**mês, dia, ano**). O uso desses catadores ajuda a garantir que os usuários podem escolher uma data ou hora válida, formatada corretamente e ajustada ao idioma do usuário.

Desta forma, o [DatePicker](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html) permite que você selecione a data que consiste em dia, mês e ano em sua interface e o [TimePicker](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html) consiste na seleção de um horário que consiste em hora e minuto.

Abaixo segue uma imagem que ilustra como é mostrado os seguintes componentes para ao usuário, lembrando que para cada versão do Android, pode ser mostrado de uma forma dependendo do tema. Veja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja como é possível [criar um DatePicker](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html#DatePicker) e [um TimePicher](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html#TimePicker) na própria documentação.

> No entanto, gostaria de saber se ao implementar os dois métodos no
>   android studio, o admin poderá ver a data e a hora que o usuário
>   marcou.

Se você enviar corretamente as datas para seu banco de dados, caso seja um banco de dados, o *admin* verá se você der permissão para ele ver, mas aí vai da sua criatividade, que neste caso já não teria mais nada a ver com o `DatePicker` e o `TimePicker`.

Comment: valeu Ack..mais uma vez vc me ajudando